# Trouble moving tons of files from OS X server attached RAID to NAS

Tags: macos, permission, nas

I am trying to move many thousands of files to a Synology NAS.

Thanks to excellent posts here and superuser, I have been using rsync a lot. But in this case, I'm getting a very high failure rate due to years of permissions problems across the board.

Any ideas on how I can get all these files copied, either by straightening out the permissions issues, or bypassing them? Once on the NAS, the permissions won't matter.

Comment: Which specific error messages are you getting? If it really are just read permission issues, `chmod`/`chown` (or using `sudo rsync ...`) should suffice.

Comment: Hi I definitely use "sudo" each time.

`So for example I'll see "rsync: opendir (location) failed: Permission denied 13 `

Many users in this network have various permissions issues, locked out of certain files and folders, while others can access, and so I'm presuming this is the same mess.

Comment: Can you spell out what chmod/chown command I could use on the entire massive directory without messing up anything?

Comment: Hold the phone! User error? I may have forgotten to use sudo *headsmack* Thank you for the clarity.

Comment: There were a small batch of files that didn't copy by rsync due to permissions problems. This actually required me to drag and drop them, which gave me a prompt to enter the administrator credentials due to permissions. And for sure I was using sudo

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these are *read* permission issues you should be able to overcome them by running

```
sudo rsync …
```

If you don't need the various read permissions on the original files, you can also use

```
sudo chown -R $USER source/dir
```

first to change file ownership to yourself.